# JS function returns undefined

Tags: javascript

The objective of the program is to create randomly a sequence of 15 DNA bases, then be able to change this sequence upon request. This is why you'll find 2 functions about random DNA creation, then a function with a mutate method.

Unfortunately, `console.log(dnaFactoried.mutate())` returns `undefined` one time in a range of 6.

here's my code:

```js
// Returns a random DNA base
const returnRandBase = () => {
  const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
  return dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] 
}

// Returns a random single stand of DNA containing 15 bases
const mockUpStrand = () => {
  const newStrand = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    newStrand.push(returnRandBase())
  }
  return newStrand
}

// functionality of creation or mutation of the dna
const pAequorFactory = (number, dnaBase) => {
  return {
    specimenNum: number,
    dna: dnaBase(),
    mutate: function () {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random()* this.dna.length);
      const toBeMutated = this.dna[random];
      const thatMutates = returnRandBase();
      if (toBeMutated == thatMutates) {
        this.mutate();
      } else {
        this.dna.splice(random, 1, thatMutates);
        return this.dna;
      } 
    }
  }
}
const dnaFactoried = pAequorFactory(1, mockUpStrand);
console.log(dnaFactoried.dna);
console.log(dnaFactoried.mutate());
```

Comment: you aren't always returning from `mutate`

Comment: Please make an effort to create an MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For instance which iteration of the loop is the one that breaks the function?

Comment: Your `mutate` function should probably just return `this.dna` at its end, instead of in the `else` branch of your `if` statement.

Comment: Seems like it got stuck in a recursive loop

Comment: You are never hitting the `false` branch of your `if` statement inside the object returned by `pAequorFactory`. If you add a `return` in the `true` branch, you'll see that you do get that value.

Comment: Found the explanation: add the return keyword (return this.method())in the if statement of the mutate method. thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `return this.mutate()` on

```
if (toBeMutated == thatMutates) {      
  return this.mutate();   
}
```

Otherwise it just returns `undefined`

```js
// Returns a random DNA base
const returnRandBase = () => {
  const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
  return dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] 
}

// Returns a random single stand of DNA containing 15 bases
const mockUpStrand = () => {
  const newStrand = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    newStrand.push(returnRandBase())
  }
  return newStrand
}

// functionality of creation or mutation of the dna
const pAequorFactory = (number, dnaBase) => {
  return {
    specimenNum: number,
    dna: dnaBase(),
    mutate: function () {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random()* this.dna.length);
      const toBeMutated = this.dna[random];
      const thatMutates = returnRandBase();
      if (toBeMutated == thatMutates) {
        return this.mutate();
      } else {
        this.dna.splice(random, 1, thatMutates);
        return this.dna;
      } 
    }
  }
}
const dnaFactoried = pAequorFactory(1, mockUpStrand);
console.log(dnaFactoried.dna);
console.log(dnaFactoried.mutate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move `return this.dna;` outside of if...else statement.